# Bounds vs Frame when making a custom view and initializing it

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, frame, bounds

I'm having some difficulties understanding the difference, and when to use what.

I know the textbook definitions. I have also searched a lot regarding this very topic. Some answers here on SO were helpful to some extent, but I feel I still don't understand this properly.

Let's say I have a aCustomView.m, and when I place UI elements within that view, I use bounds, which makes sense because it's in it's own coordinate system, but, when I initialize the view using `initWithFrame:` in my view-controller, should I use `self.view.frame` or `self.view.bounds`? Both would work, but with different results.

I really want to understand this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bounds of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to its own coordinate system (0,0).

The frame of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to the superview it is contained within.

So the difference is only a question of representation.

Comment: Just want to add, if you're using self.view.frame, it will often work because that frame happens to have an origin of 0,0.  However, as a good rule of thumb.  If you're adding a subview and want it to fill up the parent, always set the frame to its parent's bounds.

Comment: Thanks @Logan for the additional comment. It is indeed a common practice to use the parent's bounds to initialize a subview when you want to fill up the parent.